# Image is Setted only one time After Login using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, set

I am able to access name, image and other Stuff from the Facebook SDK.I am Able to Set the Image in ImageView When i Login.Then if i go back and Run Same Activity then the Login is True But image is not Setted in the ImageView.Do i have to use Shared Pref to save image? Or facebook provide this with the Session.I am using image Caching using Picasso but Image is not Setted.

```
  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        nowLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeStayDetailPage.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {

                            userID = (String) object.get("id");
                            String userName = (String) object.get("name");
                            Picasso.with(HomeStayDetailPage.this).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large").error(R.mipmap.close_hire_guide).into(facebook_image_loader_imageView);


                            System.out.println("hello userID" + userID);
                            System.out.println("hello userName" + userName);


                            //Bitmap b = (Bitmap) object.get("picture");
//                            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//                            tv.setText("Hello" + " " + userName);
                            Log.d("o/p", "name");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });


   public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return accessToken != null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

//
//        if (isLoggedIn() == true) {
//            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large").memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).error(R.drawable.close).into(facebook_image_loader_imageView, new Callback() {
//                @Override
//                public void onSuccess() {
//
//                }
//
//                @Override
//                public void onError() {
//                    //Try again online if cache failed
//                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
//                            .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large")
//                            .error(R.drawable.close)
//                            .into(facebook_image_loader_imageView, new Callback() {
//                                @Override
//                                public void onSuccess() {
//
//                                }
//
//                                @Override
//                                public void onError() {
//                                    Log.v("Picasso", "Could not fetch image");
//                                }
//                            });
//                }
//            });
//
//
//        }
```

Why i am not able to set the image after login when the onBackpressed and Call the Same Activity?

Comment: your onSuccess() method of callbackManager is not getting called while you go back to the activity. so try to save the image url and set image in onResume() or onCreate(). for more information check the lifecycle of activity

Comment: sure sunil.Do i have to maintain Session on that

Comment: no need to maintain the session just save the image url.

Comment: your calling Facebook SDK for login only once. so store the response of the user. if he is already logged use the stored information on logout delete all the details of the user. so that different user can login.

Comment: Where Do i have to Store? in SDCard or Shared Pref

Comment: save it in shared preference. but remember if different user login.. that time you need to clear your shared preferences and save it again for new user, so that you can show correct image for the every user

Comment: @sunilkushwah  i am Able to save but not able to retrieve the Data.Can't i cache the image using picasso and Display it

Comment: do you need any help..or you already solved your problem

Comment: solved it man.thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Shared Preferences to Store the Data and Access it**

```
  try {

                            userID = (String) object.get("id");
                            String userName = (String) object.get("name");
                            Picasso.with(HomeStayDetailPage.this).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large").error(R.mipmap.close_hire_guide).into(facebook_image_loader_imageView);
                            System.out.println("hello userID" + userID);
                            System.out.println("hello userName" + userName);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("id", userID);
                            editor.commit();


                            //Bitmap b = (Bitmap) object.get("picture");
//                            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//                            tv.setText("Hello" + " " + userName);
                            Log.d("o/p", "name");
                        }
```

**Access the INformation on ONcreate**

if (isLoggedIn() == true) {

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", 0);
    String response = prefs.getString("id", userID);

    Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("htis is response " + response);
    Picasso.with(HomeStayDetailPage.this).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + response + "/picture?type=large").error(R.mipmap.close_hire_guide).into(facebook_image_loader_imageView);

}
```

> Try this

Comment: I have stored in Shared pref but not able to access the Data

Answer (score 1):

it's because your image is setting only when facebook sdk return success response after fb login. you should do it outside of it.

are your doing this in activity or fragment?

Comment: this is on Activity

Comment: so try to make userid global variable and set your imageview with image if userid not null in onresume method. as well as in that above given method.